# Type script error that "set" does not exist on type "NgProgress" and property "complete" does not exist on type "NgProgress"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, nodes, tesseract

I'm developing an app from a tutorial I found online but I keep getting errors saying that "set" and "complete" do not exist on type "NgProgress" despite me adding all necessary imports and downloading the latest npm packages. This has been bugging me for a couple of days, would really appreciate the assistance.

This is the code from home.ts

```
recog() {
    let lc = this.loading.create({
      content: "Recognizing...",
      spinner: "ios",
      });
    lc.present();
    Tessaract.recognize(this.selectedImage)
      .progress((result) => {
        if (result.status == "recognizing text") {
          this.progress.set(result.progress);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert(e);
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.imageText = result.text;
      })
      .finally((ress) => {
        this.progress.complete();
        lc.dismiss();
      });
  }
```

I have gone through all the necessary npm packages and found that the NgProgress import is potentially depracated. I would like to know know why typescript does not recognize the types 'progress.complete' and 'progress.set'.

Comment: Link the libraries/modules where NgProgress is? Even better link the source of NgProgress directly.

Comment: @youdateme I link the source of NgProgress to what exactly?